# SwiftUI animation transition of conditional views

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

So, i have this little app with a button where i can change the how the main view display its items, with a grid or list.
But i would like to add a little animation when it makes its transition from one to another. I messed i little bit trying to add `withAnimation`on the button, or `.transition()` inside the views, but nothing seems to do the trick.
Any tips on how can i achieve this?

```
struct FrameworkGridView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = FrameworkGridViewModel()
    @Binding var isGrid: Bool
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Group {
                if viewModel.isGrid {
                    ScrollView {
                        LazyVGrid(columns: viewModel.columns) {
                            ForEach(MockData.frameworks) { framework in
                                FrameworkTitleView(framework: framework, isGrid: $viewModel.isGrid)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        viewModel.selectedFramework = framework
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.isShowingDetailView) {
                        DetailView(framework: viewModel.selectedFramework ?? MockData.sampleFramework, isShowingDetailView: $viewModel.isShowingDetailView, isGrid: $viewModel.isGrid)
                    }
                } else {
                    List {
                        ForEach(MockData.frameworks) { framework in
                            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(framework: framework, isShowingDetailView: $viewModel.isShowingDetailView, isGrid: $viewModel.isGrid)) {       
                                FrameworkTitleView(framework: framework, isGrid: $viewModel.isGrid)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button {
                    viewModel.isGrid.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: viewModel.isGrid ? "list.dash" : "square.grid.2x2")
                }
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

[[image]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`matchedGeometryEffect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/matchedgeometryeffect(id:in:properties:anchor:issource:)#). Check out [WWDC 2020: What's New in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10041/?time=1141) starting around 19 minutes in. [The SwiftUI Lab](https://swiftui-lab.com/matchedgeometryeffect-part1/) also has a couple of articles about it.